# Reactjs: Is it necessary to copy object in component state before modifying it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose my my reactjs component has two states:

```
a: {
    a: 1
},
b: [1, 2, 3]
```

Now I want them to become:

```
a: {
    a: 1,
    b: true
},
b: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is it correct to do it by:

```
this.state.a.b = true;
b = this.state.b.push(4);
this.setState({
    a: this.state.a,
    b: b
});
```

If not, what is the appropriate way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do it.

```
  this.setState({
    a: Object.assign({}, this.state.a, { b: true }),
    b: [...this.state.b, 4]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The state properties should be replaced, and not mutated:

```
this.setState({
    a: { // create new a object
        a: this.state.a.a,
        b: true
    },
    b: this.state.b.concat([4]) // create new b array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):

**Do Not Modify State Directly**

For example, this will not re-render a component:

```
// Wrong
this.state.comment = 'Hello';
```

Instead, use setState():

```
// Correct
this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
```

**So it is not necessary to copy an object before modifying it, if you use setState**

**So your code might look like this:**

```
this.setState({
    a: (this.state.a.b = true),
    b: this.state.b.push(4)
})
```